# How do I find out which RequireJS run javascript slows my page so much?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requirejs, dhtmlx

I have this big complex page which uses `RequireJS` to do a lot of `jQuery` `ajax`-based juggling to draw stuff. Now when I run it locally, it goes snappy fast. (testing on `Chromium`)

Bun when I run it on our server, it slows down to crazy. Opening panels and tabs is just sluggish like mud.

**However**, it does not seem to be the Ajax thing. Requests and responses are still pretty quick, as judged by the development console. And besides, switching a tab doesn't even do any Ajax and it still takes 5 - 10 seconds.

How am I going to find out what causes this lag? There are way too many scripts and libraries to just do 'dumb' dumps of timings to the console.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about tabs, you're not talking about browser tabs right? Because then it's your browser. You could use the profiler that is built in Chrome. Use F12 -> Profiler and you will get a result of the JS that was executed and what functions took how long.

Comment: True, sorry for the confusion. I am talking about `dhtmlx` elements. It's all on the webpage. I will check out the profiler but in the past I couldn't get it to work for me for reasons I forgot. -edit- wow it has improved since I last used it 500 gazillion years ago. I'll try it out.